# Delete selected checkboxes

Tags: android, checkbox, delete-row

I am trying to get the selected checkboxes deleted. I have no clue what to do after this code below:
I am using a simple cursor adapter. I also want to know how I could select and deselect all the checkboxes. I had researched everything but can't find any answer. I've been stuck for 3 days. ALso, Im not sure if the code below is even the correct path i need.

```
public class SecondCheckedListView extends ListActivity {

 private Cursor mCursor;
 private Long mRowId;
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondcheckedlistview);
    db.open();
    fillData();




 }

private void fillData() {
    mCursor = db.getAllContacts();
   startManagingCursor(mCursor);
   String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_FIRSTNAME, DBAdapter.KEY_LASTNAME}; 
   int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2};
   SimpleCursorAdapter d = 
           new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowcheckedlistview, mCursor, from, to);
       setListAdapter(d);


}

public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final int mLayout;
    private final Cursor mCursor;
    private final int mNameIndex;
    private final int mIdIndex;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    private final class ViewHolder {
            public TextView firstname;
            public TextView lastname;
            public CheckBox cBox;
    }
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayout = layout;
        this.mCursor = c;
        this.mNameIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_FIRSTNAME);
        this.mIdIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.ROW_ID);
        this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (mCursor.moveToPosition(pos)) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mLayout, null);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.firstname = (TextView)     convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                viewHolder.lastname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                viewHolder.cBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bcheck);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            }else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            String firstname = mCursor.getString(mNameIndex);
            String rowId = mCursor.getString(mIdIndex);


}
        return convertView;
    }



    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean "delete"?  You want to remove the checkbox from the listview?  You might need
to do something like 
     viewHolder.RemoveView(cBox);

If you want to select/delsect all checkboxes, you'll probably want that based upon some other botton or checkbox.  I do that with another checkbox like so:

```
private OnClickListener setSelectAllListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        selectAllTouched = true;
        if (!selectAllCheck.isChecked()) {
           selectAll = false;
           studs.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
        else {
           selectAll = true;
           studs.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

And then in my custom adapter that does stuff with each checkbox in a listview, I use this:

```
 if (selectAllTouched) {
            if(selectAll){
                holder.here.setChecked(true);
                itemCheckedHere.set(pos, true);
                int who= new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                mDbHelper.updateAttend(who, classnum, ATTEND, 1, attendDate );
            }
            else{
                holder.here.setChecked(false);
                itemCheckedHere.set(pos, false);
                int who = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                mDbHelper.updateAttend(who, classnum, ATTEND, 0, attendDate );
            }
        }
```

I used a sparse array, itemCheckedHere, to hold the values of all the check boxes so scrolling doesn't change the values on resued views.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I mean is I wanted to delete the certain row where the checkbox is checked. My ListActivity is from a database I had created.

Comment: in that case you want to remove viewHolder and then notifyDataSetChanged or Cursor.requery to have your listview reflect the change